# Type error: Is not a function in NODE JS DIscord Bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, typeerror

```js
const DBM = {};
const DiscordJS = require("discord.js");
const Bot = DBM.Bot = {};

Bot.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!");
});

Bot.login("token");

if (DiscordJS.version < "12.0.0") {
    console.log("This version of Discord Bot Maker requires Discord.JS v12\n Please use ...");
    throw new Error("Need Discord.JS v12 to Run!!!");
}
```

[image]

I am making a discord bot, but I got an error like that, anyone knows how to fix it?

Comment: Please post your code here as text, not images.

Comment: Your clearly not understanding what you wrote.
This is not something we can help on StackoverFlow.
Please follow the tutorial at: http://discordjs.guide/

Comment: This is not an appropriately asked question, you require teaching, not a solution. I don't want to discourage you from building it, so I suggest that you please follow PLASMA chicken's suggestion above. It is a great thing that you're trying to do. StackOverflow just isn't a learning platform, it's an information collective created by a community of developers that filter unwanted info, such as this question. That doesn't mean it is a bad question, but it does mean that it is a question that's more appropriate for a platform like Reddit, or Quora.

Comment: To give you some guidance though, I would feel guilty if I did not. It is telling you that `bot.on(...)` is not a function, which means exactly that. You need to understand what a function does, how to write one, and why you use them. Until you understand that I can't explain the subject any further. Check out this page, I think it will really help you. https://computersciencewiki.org/index.php/Functions Please continue to investigate programming concepts and paradigms. The Programming communities may be harsh, but they are full of very smart people.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Bot` has to be:

```js
const Bot = new DiscordJS.Client();
```

And you can delete the if-statement with the version. If you use `npm i discord.js@latest` in your terminal it will be the latest version of discord.js.
And you have another mistake in your code. You want to console log your bots name. You can do that by doing:

```js
console.log(`Logged in as ${Bot.user.tag}`);
```

You have to use -> ` <- if you want to place variables inside a string. And you said `client.user.tag`, that is not possible, because you don't have a variable named `client`, you just have a variable named `Bot`, which is your client.